# calculating input values using javascript ( new fields )

Tags: javascript

```js
<script>
var ex=1; 
function add1(){
a1=Number(document.form.present_+ex.value);
a2=Number(document.form.total_+ ex.value);

g1=(a1/a2)*100;

document.form. percentage_ex. value=g1;
 
}
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" > 

var ex=1; 
function Add() { 

var tbl = document.getElementById('tab'); 
var lastRow = tbl.rows.length; 
var iteration = lastRow - 1; 
var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow); 
 
 var firstCell = row.insertCell(0); 
 var e=document.createElement('input');
e.type='text';
e.name='register_'+ex;
e.id='register_'+ex;
e.placeholder='Register Num';
e.className='form-control'; 

firstCell.appendChild(e);

 
var secondCell = row.insertCell(1); 
var eve=document.createElement('input');
eve.type='text';
eve.name='present_'+ex;
eve.id='present_'+ex;
eve.placeholder='Present Hours';
eve.className='form-control'; 
secondCell.appendChild(eve);


var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2); 
var e1 = document.createElement('input');
e1.type='text';
e1.name='total_'+ex;
e1.id='total_'+ex;
e1.placeholder='Total Hours';
e1.className='form-control'; 
thirdCell.appendChild(e1);


var fourthCell = row.insertCell(3); 
var e2 = document.createElement('input');
e2.type='text';
e2.name='percentage_'+ex;
e2.id='percentage_'+ex;
e2.placeholder='Percentage';
e2.readOnly="true"
e2.className='form-control'; 
fourthCell.appendChild(e2);

 ex++; 
sampleform.ex.value=ex; 
 }

</script>
```

```html
 <form action="" method="post" name="sampleform">
    
    
 
      <table id="tab" class="table table-responsive" 
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="register_0" id="register_0" placeholder="Register Num" class="form-control" required></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="present_0" id="present_0" placeholder="Present Hours" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" ></td>
          <td>
          <input type="text" name="total_0" id="total_0" placeholder="Total Hours" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" >
          </td>
          <td>
          <input type="text" name="percentage_0" id="percentage_0" placeholder="Percentage" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"  readonly>
          </td>
          <td><button type="button" name="add" onclick="Add();" class="btn btn-block btn-sm" width="50px;">ADD</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </center>
    <lable>
      <input name="ex" type="hidden" id="ex" value="1">
    </lable>
    <br />
    
    <button type="button" onclick="javascript:add1();" class=" btn btn-info">Cal..</button>
      <input type ="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
    </center>
  </form>
```

> Output screen . Percentage calculation is displayed blank.
>   I am not perfect in Javascript.. I want to show percentage entered in an input box in next input box named percentage. Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Comment: `document.form` does not exist. One correct syntax is `document.forms.sampleform[ "present_" + ex ]`. And do not use `ex.value`, just use ex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your script. Use document.forms['formname']['formvalue'].

Eg: document.forms['sampleform']['present_'+ex]

And change the "ex" variable to 0, because fields have name 'present_0', 'total_0' ...

```
var ex=0; 
function add1(){
a1=Number(document.forms['sampleform']['present_'+ex].value);
a2=Number(document.forms['sampleform']['total_'+ex].value);

g1=(a1/a2)*100;

document.forms['sampleform']['percentage_' + ex].value=g1;

}
```

UPDATE: fixed Add() function:

```
function Add() { 
ex++; //this must be executed at the beginning.
var tbl = document.getElementById('tab'); 
var lastRow = tbl.rows.length; 
var iteration = lastRow - 1; 
var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow); 

 var firstCell = row.insertCell(0); 
 var e=document.createElement('input');
e.type='text';
e.name='register_'+ex;
e.id='register_'+ex;
e.placeholder='Register Num';
e.className='form-control'; 

firstCell.appendChild(e);


var secondCell = row.insertCell(1); 
var eve=document.createElement('input');
eve.type='text';
eve.name='present_'+ex;
eve.id='present_'+ex;
eve.placeholder='Present Hours';
eve.className='form-control'; 
secondCell.appendChild(eve);


var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2); 
var e1 = document.createElement('input');
e1.type='text';
e1.name='total_'+ex;
e1.id='total_'+ex;
e1.placeholder='Total Hours';
e1.className='form-control'; 
thirdCell.appendChild(e1);


var fourthCell = row.insertCell(3); 
var e2 = document.createElement('input');
e2.type='text';
e2.name='percentage_'+ex;
e2.id='percentage_'+ex;
e2.placeholder='Percentage';
e2.readOnly="true"
e2.className='form-control'; 
fourthCell.appendChild(e2);

sampleform.ex.value=ex; 
 }
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8h3rv3jh/1/

Comment: thanks for your reply @stefano castriotta .. but does not work.. first row will be work.. another rows does not calculate the vaues..

Comment: I fixed the script, the ex++ line was at the end of the Add() function, it must be at the beginning, see the updated JsFiddle